# What is the best way to organize code while building multiple offices in a single projet with VueJS and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, single-page-application

I'm building a SPA using VueJS (with VueRouter) and Laravel and I need to create multiple office within the same application. The application will handle 3 actors : clients, professionals and administrators. Those actors can all login to an account and access different functionnalities. The clients are concerned by the client office (www.myapplication.com) and the pro / admins by the pro office (www.myapplication.com/pro).

I'm a bit lost on how I will manage the components and the views for the two apps.

I thought about going that way :

```
assets/
    js/
      client/
        components/
        views/
        app.js
        App.vue
        routes.js
      pro/
        components/
        views/
        app.js
        App.vue
        routes.js
```

In the routes/web.php there will be two routes :

```
Route::get('/', function () { return view('client/welcome'); });
Route::get('/pro', function () { return view('pro/welcome'); });
```

In my webpack.mix.js, I will have something like this :

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/client/app.js', 'public/js/client')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/client/app.scss', 'public/css/client');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/pro/app.js', 'public/js/pro')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/pro/app.scss', 'public/css/pro');
```

And then in the blades.php I will have :

```
views/
    client/
        welcome.blade.php (<script src="/js/client/app.js"></script>)
    pro/
        welcome.blade.php (<script src="/js/pro/app.js"></script>)
```

Of course the app won't be an entire SPA since there will be a refresh while going from client to pro offices.

What do you think of this strategy ? Does it seems correct ? Do you have other ideas ?

Comment: It depends on how you build your app.  We also have multiple profiles, but many of our components are the same for any of them, just the data may be different, or the actions they can perform.
If everything is going to be entirely different, your setup doesn't seem too bad to me...